# When I want to open an old .java file, IntelliJ is not an option to open it

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently had to reinstall IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 and it works fine, but when I want to open an old `.java` IntelliJ is not an option to open it. This is what the `.java` file looks like in my folders:

[image: .java file in myfolders].

I am wondering why the type is being shown as Intellij IDEA2017.2 instead of a `.java` file.

Also, when I click to open the file, I only get these options:

[image: Options for opening Java file] instead of IntelliJ.

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-2624477

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now!